# Windows 10 UWP VpnPlugin Connection Failures

Tags: c#, uwp, vpn

I am developing a UWP VPN Plugin. In later stage it should handle OpenVPN. In the first stage I am trying to understand the VpnPlugin to get it work in the simplest possible way. For testing I am using Android's ToyVpn test Server on a Debian VM (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/server/linux). Unfortunately the VpnPlugin is poor and lousy documented, no Guideline - no Nothing. The Github examples are useless and not working either, even https://github.com/ysc3839/UWPToyVpn gives only Rough orientation. I was able to successfully do the Handshake with the Server who responds with a Parameter chain. When it Comes to start the Connection, an exception is thrown that the device is not connected. I am running out of Options and any help would greatly appreciated.

public sealed class ToyVpnPlugin : IVpnPlugIn
    {
        DatagramSocket _datagramSocket;
        public async void Connect(VpnChannel channel)
        {
            //string parameters = default;
            string serverPort = "8000";
            string secret = "test";

```
        _datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        _datagramSocket.MessageReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            DataReader dataReader = e.GetDataReader();
            if (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0 && dataReader.ReadByte() == 0)
            {
                var parameters = dataReader.ReadString(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
                ConfigureAndConnect(channel, parameters);
            }
        };

        var serverHostName = channel.Configuration.ServerHostNameList[0];

        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(channel.Configuration.CustomField);
        var firstChild = xmlDocument.FirstChild;
        if (firstChild.Name.Equals("ToyVpnConfig"))
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in firstChild.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (childNode.Name.Equals("ServerPort")) serverPort = childNode.InnerText;
                else if (childNode.Name.Equals("Secret")) secret = childNode.InnerText;
            }
        }

        await _datagramSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHostName, serverPort);
        await HandShake(_datagramSocket, secret);
    }

    public void Disconnect(VpnChannel channel)
    {
        channel.Stop();
    }

    public void GetKeepAlivePayload(VpnChannel channel, out VpnPacketBuffer keepAlivePacket)
    {
        keepAlivePacket = null;
    }

    public void Encapsulate(VpnChannel channel, VpnPacketBufferList packets, VpnPacketBufferList encapulatedPackets)
    {
        while (packets.Size > 0)
        {
            VpnPacketBuffer vpnPacketBuffer = packets.RemoveAtBegin();
            var buffer = vpnPacketBuffer.Buffer;
            VpnPacketBufferStatus vpnPacketBufferStatus = vpnPacketBuffer.Status;
            encapulatedPackets.Append(vpnPacketBuffer);
        }
    }

    public void Decapsulate(VpnChannel channel, VpnPacketBuffer encapBuffer, VpnPacketBufferList decapsulatedPackets, VpnPacketBufferList controlPacketsToSend)
    {
        while (encapBuffer != null)
        {
            decapsulatedPackets.Append(encapBuffer);
        }
    }

    async Task HandShake(DatagramSocket datagramSocket, string secret)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var dataWriter = new DataWriter(datagramSocket.OutputStream)
            {
                UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8
            };
            dataWriter.WriteByte(0);
            dataWriter.WriteString(secret);
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            dataWriter.DetachStream();
        }
    }

    void ConfigureAndConnect(VpnChannel vpnChannel, string parameters)
    {
        parameters = parameters.TrimEnd();
        uint mtu = 1500;
        List<HostName> ipv4InclusionHostNames = new List<HostName>();
        List<HostName> dnsServerHostNames = new List<HostName>();
        VpnRouteAssignment vpnRouteAssignment = new VpnRouteAssignment();
        var ipv4InclusionRoutes = vpnRouteAssignment.Ipv4InclusionRoutes;            
        foreach (var parameter in parameters.Split(null))
        {
            var fields = parameter.Split(",");
            try
            {
                switch (fields[0])
                {
                    case "m":
                        mtu = uint.Parse(fields[1]);
                        break;
                    case "a":
                        ipv4InclusionHostNames.Add(new HostName(fields[1]));
                        break;
                    case "r":
                        ipv4InclusionRoutes.Add(new VpnRoute(new HostName(fields[1]), (byte)uint.Parse(fields[2])));
                        break;
                    case "d":
                        dnsServerHostNames.Add(new HostName(fields[1]));
                        break;
                    case "s":
                        //TODO "SearchDomain"
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        VpnDomainNameAssignment vpnDomainNameAssignment = new VpnDomainNameAssignment();
        vpnDomainNameAssignment.DomainNameList.Add(new VpnDomainNameInfo(".", VpnDomainNameType.Suffix, dnsServerHostNames, null));

        try
        {   
            vpnChannel.AssociateTransport(_datagramSocket, null);
            vpnChannel.StartExistingTransports(ipv4InclusionHostNames, null, null, vpnRouteAssignment, vpnDomainNameAssignment, mtu, 65535, false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            vpnChannel.TerminateConnection(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try to see if I can involve someone on this issue.

Comment: Thanks Barry... In the meantime I was able to figure out why I was loosing the device all the time. There is a Problem with Async and Task stuff. I did some changes in Handshake: IAsyncAction HandShake(… and returned a Task as AsyncAction. Then the Handshake gets called with .AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); There is a lot of documentation and Guideline left for Microsoft as there is no Information anywhere how to handle this on the first view "simple api" properly.

Comment: +1 on the nearly total lack of documentation. I am working on getting a VPNClient working as well and have hit many of the same walls referenced here. There's a few few posts on SO discussing this topic. Are you willing to post your code out to github so that others can benefit from your hard work? I'd be interested in trying it out for one

Comment: Certainly, give me some time to prepare a Test Project and upload to Github. I keep you posted...

Comment: Find it here: https://github.com/marcusrunge/ToyVpn (I will write a few lines of documentation when I have time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be unconfirmed working, any better idea or suggestions are greatly appreciated as I figured this out by more or less "fishing"...:

```
namespace Background
{
public enum HandshakeState { Waiting, Received, Canceled };
public sealed class SecurepointVpnPlugin : IVpnPlugIn
{
    DatagramSocket _datagramSocket;
    HandshakeState _handshakeState;
    public void Connect(VpnChannel channel)
    {
        string serverPort = "8000";
        string secret = "test";
        string parameters = null;

        _datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        channel.AssociateTransport(_datagramSocket, null);

        _datagramSocket.MessageReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            DataReader dataReader = e.GetDataReader();
            if (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0 && dataReader.ReadByte() == 0)
            {
                parameters = dataReader.ReadString(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
                _handshakeState = HandshakeState.Received;
            }
        };

        var serverHostName = channel.Configuration.ServerHostNameList[0];

        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(channel.Configuration.CustomField);
        var firstChild = xmlDocument.FirstChild;
        if (firstChild.Name.Equals("ToyVpnConfig"))
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in firstChild.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (childNode.Name.Equals("ServerPort")) serverPort = childNode.InnerText;
                else if (childNode.Name.Equals("Secret")) secret = childNode.InnerText;
            }
        }

        _datagramSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHostName, serverPort).AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        _handshakeState = HandshakeState.Waiting;
        HandShake(_datagramSocket, secret).AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (_handshakeState == HandshakeState.Received) ConfigureAndConnect(channel, parameters);
        else channel.Stop();
    }

    public void Disconnect(VpnChannel channel)
    {
        channel.Stop();
    }

    public void GetKeepAlivePayload(VpnChannel channel, out VpnPacketBuffer keepAlivePacket)
    {
        keepAlivePacket = null;
    }

    public void Encapsulate(VpnChannel channel, VpnPacketBufferList packets, VpnPacketBufferList encapulatedPackets)
    {
        while (packets.Size > 0) encapulatedPackets.Append(packets.RemoveAtBegin());
    }

    public void Decapsulate(VpnChannel channel, VpnPacketBuffer encapBuffer, VpnPacketBufferList decapsulatedPackets, VpnPacketBufferList controlPacketsToSend)
    {            
        decapsulatedPackets.Append(encapBuffer);
    }

    IAsyncAction HandShake(DatagramSocket datagramSocket, string secret)
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var dataWriter = new DataWriter(datagramSocket.OutputStream)
                {
                    UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8
                };
                dataWriter.WriteByte(0);
                dataWriter.WriteString(secret);
                await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                dataWriter.DetachStream();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                switch (_handshakeState)
                {
                    case HandshakeState.Waiting:
                        break;
                    case HandshakeState.Received:
                        return;
                    case HandshakeState.Canceled:
                        throw new OperationCanceledException();
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }).AsAsyncAction();
    }

    void ConfigureAndConnect(VpnChannel vpnChannel, string parameters)
    {
        parameters = parameters.TrimEnd();
        uint mtuSize = 68;
        var assignedClientIPv4list = new List<HostName>();
        var dnsServerList = new List<HostName>();
        VpnRouteAssignment assignedRoutes = new VpnRouteAssignment();
        VpnDomainNameAssignment assignedDomainName = new VpnDomainNameAssignment();
        var ipv4InclusionRoutes = assignedRoutes.Ipv4InclusionRoutes;
        foreach (var parameter in parameters.Split(null))
        {
            var fields = parameter.Split(",");
            switch (fields[0])
            {
                case "m":
                    mtuSize = uint.Parse(fields[1]);
                    break;
                case "a":
                    assignedClientIPv4list.Add(new HostName(fields[1]));
                    break;
                case "r":
                    ipv4InclusionRoutes.Add(new VpnRoute(new HostName(fields[1]), (byte)(int.Parse(fields[2]))));
                    break;
                case "d":
                    dnsServerList.Add(new HostName(fields[1]));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        assignedRoutes.Ipv4InclusionRoutes = ipv4InclusionRoutes;
        assignedDomainName.DomainNameList.Add(new VpnDomainNameInfo(".", VpnDomainNameType.Suffix, dnsServerList, null));

        try
        {
            vpnChannel.StartExistingTransports(assignedClientIPv4list, null, null, assignedRoutes, assignedDomainName, mtuSize, mtuSize + 18, false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            vpnChannel.TerminateConnection(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's not working, it's just connecting, not even one byte reaches the server